# Vue.js Merge 2 files with methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have an api with routes about different topics, so i want to keep my api calls clean as possible. I try to import all the vue methods from 2 different files with 1 import.

What i tried do but not working is as following; I created 2 files that make api calls in vue methods: categories.js and expenses.js and i created an index.js file that wil import those files together. So on my main file i import the index.js file so i can use my methods from the expenses.js and categories.js file

I get the following: TypeError: this.getCategories is not a function

categories.vue

```
import * as API from '@/api'

export default {
    mixins: [API],
    mounted(){
        this.getCategories()
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import * as Categories  from './categories.js'
import * as Expenses    from './expenses.js'

export default {
    Categories,
    Expenses
}
```

categories.js

```
export default {
    methods: {
        getCategories(){
            this.$http.get('api.example.com')
                .then(response => {
                    //  response
                })
        }
    }
}
```

expenses.js

```
export default {
    methods: {
        getExpenses(){
            this.$http.get('api.example.com')
                .then(response => {
                    //  response
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your index.js to export an array:

```
import Categories  from './categories.js'
import Expenses    from './expenses.js'

export default [
  Categories,
  Expenses
]
```

Then changes the categories component to:

```
import API from '@/api'

export default {
  mixins: API, // [...API, others, more] if using more mixins.
  mounted(){
    this.getCategories()
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work i get i still get: TypeError: this.getCategories is not a function

Comment: Your index.js is importing wrong, I updated the answer.

Comment: WOW! thanks alot, you saved my life!! also thanks for the fast response i really appreciate it!